# Running groovy tests with Maven

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I have a folder structure as below

```
ProjectName 
  - src
       - test 
             - groovy
             - java
```

When I run command `mvn clean install` . It only runs Java Unit tests(Located under *src\test\java* directory)  while Groovy tests cases are not  invoked. It seems Groovy is not finding Groovy tests anymore.

Please help me in enabling groovy tests cases Execution with the help of Maven ?

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ApacheActiveMQSpike</groupId>
  <artifactId>ApacheActiveMQSpike</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ApacheActiveMQSpike</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.6-beta-2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205767/include-new-test-directory-maven-surefire-plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use `gmaven` plugin to trigger groovy tests

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-rc-3</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <fileset>
            <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.groovy</include>
            </includes>
          </fileset>
        </sources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Nice [article](http://matschaffer.com/2008/12/groovy-unit-tests-on-maven-eclipse/) about running Groovy tests in Maven.
The structure should be

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
       ....
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```