# How to specify test directory in Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, unit-testing, groovy, pom.xml

Maven handles java unit tests well by defaulting to:

```
src/test/java
```

We're writing quite a few Groovy unit tests right now, and I'd like to find a way in Maven to specify a folder such as:

```
src/test/groovy
```

as a test folder. This would help us to import a Maven project into, say, IntelliJ, without additional setup.

Someone mentioned this was possible, but I wasn't able to find a way searching the Maven docs, or SO. Does anyone know how to mark the directory in the pom?

Thank you

Update:  I am not asking how to run the tests in Maven! The tests are already running fine. I'm asking how to mark the directories as test directories in Maven.

Comment: The question you linked is how to run the tests - I'm asking a different question, how to mark the test directories. Please take the time to read the question before you close it!

Comment: Maybe this one then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205767/include-new-test-directory-maven-surefire-plugin either way, we've seen this before

Comment: in the build tag - just add testSourceDirectory  - 


  <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

Answer (score 10):

As described at http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3//maven-model/maven.html#class_build the build section of the pom.xml has an entry to specify the test folder.